# Create csv file using javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, html, ipad

can some explain me is there a way to convert the html5 local storage data into a csv file and store it inside ipad.

i have an html page with some text fields. when user click the submit button it is stored inside the html5 local storage. then i need to use that data to create a csv file and store it locally inside ipad app.

Let me tell my requirement. 1) get the text field data from the html page and save it to my local storage 2) get the data from the local storage and write into a csv file and save it inside an ipad 3) attach that file to the email from my app it self so i need the file path and file name to send it as attachment. 4)i have written an objective c function which sends the data 5) i call the objective function from javascript

These things are done in ipad application which uses html5 and javascript

Comment: What have you tried? And, by the way, there's no way to do "save a file" in the client. All you can do is to store it in a sandboxed space.

Comment: i actually tried to send an attachment to my email.

Comment: Let me tell my requirement. 1) get the text field data from the html page and save it to my local storage 2) get the data from the local storage and write into a csv file and save it inside an ipad 3) attach that file to the email from my app it self so i need the file path and file name to send it as attachment. 4)i have written an objective c function which sends the data 5) i call the objective function from javascript

Comment: These things are done in ipad application which uses html5 and javascript

Comment: Edit your question so that someone can answer without reading the comments. Your objective C function cannot access to the sandboxed file system, so you have to try something else. And I'm not even sure if you can call it from Javascript.

Comment: i am able to call objective c function from javascript.

Answer (score 0):

To write a file to the system using JavaScript, you would need to use the HTML5 File Writer API ([Can I write files with HTML5/JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4309958/can-i-write-files-with-html5-js)).