# creating csv file in ipad application using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, html, ipad

please let me know is it possible in ipad application.

Get the text field data from the html page and save it to my html5 local storage .
 Get the data from the local storage and write into a csv file and save it inside an ipad using javascript. Then able to fetch the csv file from the ipad location.

Comment: Don't post a question twice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15895691/create-csv-file-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the jquery plugins to get the data from tables eg table2csv

Also have a look at this answer: [Export to csv in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639372/export-to-csv-in-jquery)

This may work or get you half the way there, ie have the data to save to local storage?