# generate a html file with ajax data being send after callback

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am making a module in which when a user clicks on download button then a ajax request is send and some data is being send back after the call is complete . But how to write that data into a html file and automatically save it on client side ? . Is this possible via jquery ? as i am using `$.ajax` to get the data which i need to write in a html file and auto download that file on client side .

Comment: Here's a link that could get you what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19327749/javascript-blob-filename-without-link

Answer (score 0):

You can not write a file at **javascript** or **client** side
But,in html5 you can
Please find this link here

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

[Can I write files with HTML5/JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4309958/can-i-write-files-with-html5-js)

Comment: You can use HTML5's Javascript `Blob`-class, to create files client side, and then download them. As described in my comment on OP's thread.

Comment: as @NoLifeKing pointed out it's now possible with HTML5 features. Of course it's not really cross-browser yet