# Roll my own database with JavaScript & Html 5

Tags: javascript, database, html, internet-explorer, text-files

I work for a conservative healthcare company without a lot of technology support, and the IT department restricted anything to be installed. I have access to web browser (using IE 11.0.16). If I were to write my own web-application to read and write data to this textfile, and then display the data in a meaningful way. What are my resources? I know it is best to have framework & a proper SQL, and I know it's better to find another company to work for. But this is my situation and I want to build and do the best I can.

My local "web application" need to load and display information dynamically (base on what is from the database.txt) and then using javascript & html5 to display them depending on what information they are looking for. Such as catergories for Denied, Pending, Write Off, and Charge Delete. With the browser I can implement feature to allow my manger to read & filter information easily, and checking off box "Rebilled", will move the particular case from "Need to Rebill" to "Rebilled - Pending" category. And different "report" will read and interact with data differently. Since my data is sourced from 4-5 different places, such as Mainframe data, internal website, and 3rd party vendor site status. Whenever I "upload" to the database.txt, I would like the web-app "report" to be refreshed as well.

From: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

> In April 2014, it was announced on public-webapps that the Filesystem
>   API spec is not being considered by other browsers. For now, the API
>   is Chrome-specific and it's unlikely to be implemented by other
>   browsers and is no longer being standardized with the W3C.

I read this question: [Can I write files with HTML5/JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4309958/can-i-write-files-with-html5-js). But I notice the page stated it is "discontinued", what are other resources/technologies are there to achieve my requirement (using IE 11.0.16)

Comment: Will you be running a webserver (perhaps locally?) to host the files or did you intend to write a single `.html` file to be double clicked?

Comment: @musically_ut It would be a single .html file to be double clicked on a share network drive. (Each report will have their own .html file) Charge Delete, Write Off, Awaiting Coverage, Not on PCP File, and Manually Billed. (Because each report has its own requirement for different data).

Comment: Then, I'm afraid, you are out of luck. Writing/reading from disk is off limits for browsers because of security concerns. Even with a barebones `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` server, you could have read the file off the disk, manipulated it and then "written" to disk by offering a csv download. Without that, I don't think you can read and write to the FS.

Comment: You might be able to hack together your own shared database with [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API).  But, as others have said, Javascript has no native way to access the filesystem - some kind of server has to be involved.

Comment: try to use a cloud based database like firebase -> https://www.firebase.com/

Comment: It's member's personal insurance information, HIPPA policy so I can't use anything 3rd party or host my own server, only to rely on what's provided.

Comment: @musically_ut I see... Thanks for confirming. I appreciate your explanation.

Comment: Due to the limitations on what you can do,you are better of my microft access. Its a file based database that you can put in any network drive, with dev tools for building forms. It would much better for your use case then what any web technology currently has to offer